# Mysql installation procedure in hadoop cluster

Tags: mysql, hadoop

how to install & configure mysql in hadoop cluster (os centos) to access the created database in one node and accesing in other node.? can anyone post the step by step installation & confiuration procedure?

Comment: Refer the link http://www.percona.com/blog/2013/07/11/mysql-and-hadoop/

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a distributed SQL type solution, i would suggest you look at Cloudera Impala, Apache Spark SQL, or the Amazon solution Redshift.

MySQL is not designed to be distributed horizontally but rather vertically.

Comment: Thanq for ur suggestion.I want to know how to install distributed database in cloudera manager.....

Comment: Cloudera is a manager to install various Hadoop Services on the cloudera specific Hadoop distribution.
So first you need access to a cluster, or build your own with virtual machines:
http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/01/how-to-create-a-simple-hadoop-cluster-with-virtualbox/

then you can install services like Impala or Spark and learn to use those.